# Написать стили с помощью js через refs в computed vue3

Tags: vue.js

Как можно достучаться к последнему элементу через цикл чтобы с помощью $refs - написать такие стили

```css
&:last-child {
    position: relative;
  }

  &:last-child::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    left: 23px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

Через css нельзя - так как используется styled components в vue.js
Тоесть я хочу все это сделать с помощью computed.

Comment: А где сам цикл `v-for` и перебираемая в нем структура? Тут предполагается либо подробности о возникших затруднениях (конкретно: что именно не получается), либо [repro].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.$refs[this.$refs.length - 1]
```